# Error al tratar de obtener registros en un orden especifico

Tags: java, jpa

Estoy tratando de obtener los registros en un orden especifico (El orden del calendario) con base a un atributo llamado mes usando jpa, pero me tira una excepción y no entiendo por qué.

Está es mi función:

```
@Query("SELECT P FROM Periodo P WHERE P.linea = :linea ORDER BY"
        + "(P.mes = 'Enero'), (P.mes = 'Febrero'),(P.mes = 'Marzo'),"
        + "(P.mes = 'Abril'),(P.mes = 'Mayo'),(P.mes = 'Junio'),"
        + "(P.mes = 'Julio'),(P.mes = 'Agosto'),(P.mes = 'Septiembre'),"
        + "(P.mes = 'Octubre'),(P.mes = 'Noviembre'),(P.mes = 'Diciembre')")
List<Periodo> findPeriodoByLinea(@Param("linea") Linea linea);
```

Está es la excepción :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column 80 [SELECT P FROM app.core.entity.Periodo P WHERE P.linea = :linea ORDER BY (P.mes = 'Enero')]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: = near line 1, column 80 [SELECT P FROM app.core.entity.Periodo P WHERE P.linea = :linea ORDER BY (P.mes = 'Enero')]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
... 67 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a [la documentación de HQL respecto a la cláusula ORDER BY](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-ordering), lo que esta cláusula espera son una serie de propiedades de una clase o componente, dado que estas sean entidades JPA pero en tu caso le estás pasando expresiones booleanas.

Dependiendo de tus necesidades, te recomendaría cualquiera de las siguientes alternativas:

- crear una vista SQL dentro de tu base de datos con los datos ya ordenados, para así dejar más simple la expresión HQL con la cual los obtienes desde Hibernate. Ejemplo:

  `CREATE VIEW PERIODO_ORD AS
  SELECT P.*, CASE WHEN P.MES = 'ENERO' THEN 1, WHEN P.MES = 'FEBRERO' THEN 2 ... "ORDENMES" FROM PERIODO P ORDER BY ORDENMES`
- Crear una función SQL que te devuelva un valor numérico ordenado para cada nombre del día del mes y utilizarla en tu cláusula ORDER BY, por ejemplo:

  `CREATE FUNCTION ORDEN_MES(MES IN VARCHAR) RETURN NUMBER
  BEGIN
    IF UPPER(MES) = 'ENERO' RETURN 1;
    ELSEIF UPPER(MES) = 'FEBRERO' RETURN 2;
    ...
  END`
- Obtener los datos desordenados y ordenarlos mediante un `Arrays.sort(...)` en el `ArrayList` donde los almacenes.